# Different font rendering Mozilla Vs Webkit? (HTML5 Boilerplate)

Tags: css, fonts, rendering, html5boilerplate

I'm using Normalize.css in HTML5 Boilerplate and noticing Firefox 9 on OS X renders fonts differently than every other browser I'm testing with (Chrome 16, Safari 5.1.2, Opera 11.6 all behave the same)

Here's some screenshots, no padding or margins:

Firefox OS X 9.0.1:

[image]

Chrome OS X 16:

[image]

You can see Firefox is rendering the kerning, I believe, larger than the other browsers. Any ideas?

Comment: Retagged to remove `Normalization` and add `Rendering`.  The normalization tag on SO refers to database normalization.  I think the rendering tag will get you more of the right eyeballs.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with normalization. Can you paste a reduced testcase to http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fonts do render differently in different browsers. :)