# IE10 doesn't render sharp fonts for my website?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm building a website with Dreamweaver, and noticed that IE (I have IE10 on Win8) doesn't render my fonts as sharp as Chrome, see the example picture. Firefox is a bit off as well.
this problem is much more noticed when using small bold text.

Here's an example for **14px arial bold**:

[image]

CSS:

```
body { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="bold">Hello</span>
```

Maybe the problem is in the browser and not the style, but is there any solution to make the website easier on the eye of the visitor?

Comment: There is no single standard for font rendering.

Comment: I've had the same issue, nothing you can do about it. It's IEs rendering engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering font differs from IE compared to FF and Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574844/rendering-font-differs-from-ie-compared-to-ff-and-chrome)

Comment: I searched a bit on SO, where i found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721800/different-font-rendering-mozilla-vs-webkit-html5-boilerplate. In one of the answers it says qufon renders fonts the same in every browser, might be worth looking into.

Comment: maybe IE just applies the windowswide cleartype-setting to the rendered pages. never tried to turn this off to be honest

Comment: If you try to correct this your more than likely just going to end up chasing your tail, there's nothing to say that IE11 isn't just going to move the goal posts (*other metaphors available on request*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's zoom in for a closer look at your examples:

Chrome: [image]    
Firefox: [image]    
IE: [image]

Notice that Chrome and Firefox are clearly using [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) (a.k.a. [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType)), while IE isn't.  The difference probably comes down to user settings (or the browser / OS default settings, if the user hasn't changed them).

In particular, whereas Chrome and Firefox do their own text rendering, IE uses the default text rendering settings of the OS.  Apparently, since Windows 8, [ClearType has been disabled by default](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120303/cleartype-takes-a-back-seat-for-windows-8-metro/) for Metro-style applications, including IE.  Don't ask me why, though.

Anyway, the bad news is that, as a web developer, there's not a lot you can do about this.  In fact, you can't even count on subpixel rendering being *possible*, let alone enabled, for all users — it only works on certain types of displays.  You really just have to accept that the details of text rendering are going to vary between users, depending on lots of things like the browser, OS, display hardware and user settings.

**Edit:** Well, OK, you *could* try using something like [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), but that sounds like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer.  In any case, if you used that for *all* text on your site, I'd expect the performance to be pretty horrible.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, did you mean the performance in case I've used Cufon?
What do most web developers do with this problem? is there a better font type or a recommended minimum font size to use?

Comment: Yes, the "horrible performance" was in reference to using Cufón for all text (not that I've ever tried it, but that's what I'd expect). Anyway, what most developers do is just accept such variations in font rendering as a fact, and just try picking font settings that look reasonably nice and readable on most browsers. There'll always be some users with display settings that look horrible to you, and some of them may even like it that way -- for example, some people with poor eyesight actually find that disabling anti-aliasing _entirely_ makes text easier to read for them.